# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'v0' of null in dart

Tags: dart, google-chrome-app, dart2js

I feel kinda silly asking this question but I have tried everything I know and even consulted the api docs all to no avail.

My question is how to fix:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'v0' of null
```

What I am doing is compiling a dart based chrome app with dart2js using dart-sdk version 1.10 I have also tried dart-sdk version 1.9 with the same result.

All of my code is located at:
https://github.com/dragonloverlord/Pages

I am building my project in pycharm community edition 4.5 with the dart plugin if that matters.

I have tried using 'build mode=debug' but no different message was given I had the source maps set up as well but nothing changed.

The os that I am building on is linux ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to the issue and it's actually very simple!

All you have to do is move the dart scripts to the body of the document like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="html">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pages</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/index.css">
  </head>
  <body id="body">
    <div id="menubar">
      <button class="float-left" id="add-page" type="button">Add Page</button>
    </div>
    <div id="main-container">

    </div>
    <script src="packages/chrome/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
    <script src="main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Compared to having them in the head of the document like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="html">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Pages</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/index.css">
    <script src="packages/chrome/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
    <script src="main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
  </head>
  <body id="body">
    <div id="menubar">
      <button class="float-left" id="add-page" type="button">Add Page</button>
    </div>
    <div id="main-container">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

A very simple fix that is often forgotten!

Also adding defer to the dart script will fix the issue like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html id="html">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Pages</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/index.css">
        <script src="packages/chrome/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
        <script src="main.dart" type="application/dart" defer></script>
      </head>
      <body id="body">
        <div id="menubar">
          <button class="float-left" id="add-page" type="button">Add Page</button>
        </div>
        <div id="main-container">

        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Interesting, seems to be a timing issue then. Maybe worth a bug report.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer exactly what I was thinking as this was not a problem in previous versions I have not tried compiling the bleeding edge version yet though so it might be fixed already.

Comment: I guess not, can't remember seeing it in bug reports.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer It's a timing issue as adding defer to the dart script tag fixes the issue. I have added the workaround to my answer as well. It does generate a file not found error but that does not really matter as the app functions again.